# Using scanf to read an integer or a string

Tags: c

How can I use scanf to read either an int or a string?

What I'm trying to do is:

```
printf("Enter Your Guess, 0 - 100: "); /* Input your guess */

scanf("%as", &pass);

printf("%s", pass);
```

In this program the player can either chose to enter a number or pass how can I scan either the number or the word pass. Is there and if statement I can put in or something I've been going into this for like 1 hour

Comment: Use a `fgets` followed by combination of `strcmp` and `strtoul`.

Answer (score 2):

scan in a string, and determine whether it is made entirely of legal symbols for a number or whether the string says `"pass"`, and if it is a number, than you can convert it to the type of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a workaround would be to simply read a string all the time and use atoi or snprintf to convert the desired string to a number if it contains no other characters except [0-9]

Comment: Using `snprintf()` won't convert a string to an integer; presumably, you meant `sscanf()`.  Using `strtol()` or `strtod()` or one of their relatives would probably be a good choice — though they are subtle functions which require care to be used properly.